# PHP driven site needs password change

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, change-password

I have inherited a website that needs the password changed that accesses the database.  I can see that there are two tables within the database but neither of them have username or password info.

The previous web guy moved out of the country and can't be reached.  I am not up-to-speed enough to figure this out.  I have gone through all the files to try and find the answer but can't get it.

It's hosted by goDaddy.com and I have changed the passwords there but it didn't change this login info.

www.executivehomerents.com/cpanel <-this brings up the prompt for the username & password which I won't give out but the page only gives you 5 choices and none of them deal with changing the password.  They are simply to change the data in the tables.

If you go to:
http://www.websitedatabases.com/  <=this is the company that the PHPMagic program was purchased from--
They have no contact number.

Here is another page that might help:  http://www.executivehomerents.com/cpanel/dbinput/setup.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the password to the database has changed - I can't quite read from your description whether that is what is the case -  you will probably need to find and change it in the PHP application itself. It is likely to reside in some configuration file.

What I would do:

- Download the whole project using FTP
- Make a full-text search for the database server name (usually `localhost`)
- Alternatively, search for `mysql_connect()` or similar commands depending on what library was used
- That way, you would probably find the file in which the password is set.
- Change the password to the new one that was (I assume) set in the hosting provider's control panel
- Upload the changed file
- Site should work.

No guarantee you will find it that way, but that's how it usually works.

Comment: OK, I finally figured it out.  It was actually a locked file on the GoDaddy site that I had to reset.  I only had to call them 3 TIMES to get the answer!  thanks so much for your advice.  It was good advice.